# How to parse JSON with N child objects

Tags: json, retrofit, moshi

I am trying to parse a JSON response I am receiving from an 3rd party API.

The response returns a json object with N child objects.

The children all conform to the same model/class, but the amount of children can change.

Had it been an array of objects, it would have been trivial, but I am not sure how to do it with an object holding N objects.

I believe I need a custom typeadapter but I can't seem to get it done.

Here is the JSON:

```
"api":{
   "results": 94
   "leagues": {
         "1":{
            "league_id":"1"
            "name":"2018 Russia World Cup"
            "country":"World"
            "season":"2018"
            "season_start":"2018-06-14"
             }
         "2":{...}
         "3":{...}
         "4":{...}
         ...
         "N":{...}
          }
      }
```

So basically it is the "leagues" object I am trying to parse.

I am hoping to end up with a `List<League>`

For instance, the the root object could have this model:

```
class Api {
   val results: Int
   val leagues: List<League>
}
```

Comment: JSON is never an object; its always a string. Please add the expected output as it is unclear what you want to achieve. To parse JSON you always use `JSON.parse(str)`.

Comment: Do you want to acheive in Java ?

Comment: I am writing in kotlin, but java is fine. I think the custom typeadapter I need is what I want inspiration for.

Comment: @AndersPedersen I think, if you want to store league as lists. it is better to redesign  your json data like below. `{
    "api": {
        "results": 94,
        "leagues": [
            {
                "league_id": "1",
                "name": "2018 Russia World Cup",
                "country": "World",
                "season": "2018",
                "season_start": "2018-06-14"
            },
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {}
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: I agree, but I have no control over the data output

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go for a `Map<String, League>` (assuming the entries in the map would be of class `League`) for the type of `leagues`.

```
class Api {
  val results: Int
  val leagues: Map<String, League>
}
```

I think the things to consider here are mostly regarding the order I suppose. If you need to maintain the order of the entries, I'm not sure if Moshi does it automatically or if you need to use a specific implementation of `Map` to guarantee this.

Comment: Seems you are right, Moshi can work it out if I use Map instead of List.

Comment: Yes. As for the order, I'm not too sure about it. Json doesn't say dictionaries are ordered, so I'd assume Moshi also doesn't put them in any particular order

Answer (score 0):

You can get make the league list in a custom adapter.

```
data class Api(val results: Int, val leagues: List<League>)

object LeagueListAdapter {
  @FromJson fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader, leagueAdapter: JsonAdapter<League>): List<League> {
    reader.beginObject()
    val result = mutableListOf<League>()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      reader.skipName()
      result += leagueAdapter.fromJson(reader)!!
    }
    reader.endObject()
    return result
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add the adapter when building your Moshi instance (`Moshi.Builder.add`).